# Jquery Dialog saving information in the database

Tags: jquery

I am a beginner in programming with Jquery. I'm using as a Dialog box for editing of information, must save them in the database. But I have no idea how to do, someone could give me a little help? (Edit: translated from Portugese)

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    show: 'clip',
    hide: 'clip',
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            $('form').submit();
            $(this).dialog('close');
        },
        'Cancel': function() {
            $(this).dialog('close');
        }
    }
});


$('#dialog_link').click(function() {
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    return false;
});
```

Obrigada

Comment: Do you want to save the information to the database from the web server, in response to the form submission, or do you want to somehow send the data directly from JavaScript, for example via an AJAX call? If from the web server, then is the jQuery code already submitting the form correctly?

Comment: o código parece bem. O que parece ser o problema?

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a form, the page refreshes instantly, so the .dialog("close") is unnecessary. All the other lines seems good and if it wont work, then it is not a jQuery problem.